# JavaScript - undefined passed in as a parameter *name*?

Tags: javascript

I have just come across a function which accepts a parameter actually called 'undefined'. It is something like this:

```
(function($,undefined) {
    // Do something
})(jQuery);
```

Either I'm going crazy, or there is no logical reason for this to be here as, well, undefined is undefined is undefined. Please can someone confirm either way? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the answers and for pointing out that it's a duplicate - sorry about that. I had a search initially but all I found was about passing in undefined when calling the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a classic trick to have an `undefined` variable to check against, typically:

```js
if (someVar === undefined) {}

// instead of:

if (typeof someVar === 'undefined') {}
```

Notice that the wrapper IIFE does not pass any second argument, making the `undefined` parameter effectively `undefined`.

Comment: What is the downside to using `if (typeof someVar === 'undefined') {}`?

Comment: just longer to type and usually not shorten by JS minifiers.

Comment: @ghybs can't the value of `undefined` be changed and that's why `if (typeof someVar === 'undefined') {}` is occasionally recommended?

Comment: @dimwittedanimal yes `undefined` was modifiable. The above trick shields against that, since it uses a locally scoped variable. `if (typeof somVar === 'undefined'){}` is not _occasionally_ recommended, it is the primary way of checking that. But you have plenty alternatives to achieve the same effect, provided you take some precautions.

Comment: @ghybs Thanks! Missed/forgot that it was a local var.